# How to bind entire object to control in XAML

Tags: wpf

We can bind properties of controls to Data Context like

Is there any way to bind control to existing Control in Code behind ?

If i already have text box in My Data context is there any way to bind this textbox in XAML to another text box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot bind all the properties from one control to another control in datacontext automatically. But you can bind your entire control from `DataContext` into `ContentControl` as `Content`.

Let's say you have 'MyTextBox' property in your current `DataContext`. Then in XAML you can do the following:

```
 <ContentControl Content="{Binding MyTextBox}" />
```

Which probably should work (if you do not assign `MyTextBox` as child somewhere else also)

Comment: It works as I want.
Previously i was Using 
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=MyTextBox}"></ContentPresenter>
Whats Difference or which is Better way ?

Comment: @010, ContentControl is a base for building controls which have something to be displayed inside them. In your case there will be no difference between `ContentControl` and `ContentPresenter`. See some more details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287995/whats-the-difference-between-contentcontrol-and-contentpresenter