# WPF - Hosting content inside a UserControl

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I'm trying to create a user control that has a `Grid` with two rows.
the first row for a title and the second one for a content that will be defined outside the user control such as a `Button` in our example.

Somehow I didn't get it to work.

UserControl1 xaml:

```
  <Grid Background="LightBlue">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Title" FontSize="30" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow xaml:

```
 <Grid>
    <local:UserControl1>
        <Button>Click me</Button>
    </local:UserControl1>
</Grid>
```

The picture below should explain what's my problem:
[image]

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The following code

```
<local:UserControl1>
    <Button>Click me</Button>
</local:UserControl1>
```

Means that you set `UserControl1`'s Content property to be that button. This button simply replaces that `UserControls1`'s markup. So all the things that you have in UserControl1.xaml are not there any more.

**EDIT**

If you want your UserControl to host some markup that will be set somewhere outside of it, you can add a `DependencyProperty` to it, for example:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets additional content for the UserControl
    /// </summary>
    public object AdditionalContent
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(AdditionalContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AdditionalContentProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AdditionalContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("AdditionalContent", typeof(object), typeof(UserControl1),
          new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

And add some element to it's markup to host that additional content. Here's an example extending the markup you provided:

```
<UserControl ... Name="userControl">
    <Grid Background="LightBlue">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="Title" FontSize="30" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding AdditionalContent, ElementName=userControl}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now you can use it as following:

```
<local:UserControl1>
    <local:UserControl1.AdditionalContent>
        <Button>Click me</Button>
    </local:UserControl1.AdditionalContent>
</local:UserControl1>
```

Comment: Why use an additional dependency property and not just replace the Control Template and bind to the content property?

Comment: I agree with you. I saw your answer just after I've posted mine. It was me voting your's up

Comment: The explanation of why it's not working is great, but I found @blindmeis's answer to be more helpful.

Comment: Instead of using `<local:UserControl1.AdditionalContent>` you can simply use `[ContentProperty("AdditionalContent")]` attribute on the class and then it's possible to have custom controls just inside the control's content. This is great, because no one can destroy it by accidentally setting the content instead of the `AdditionalContent`.

Comment: Thank you. Your code helped me to built usercontrol that host other control but content of the ContentPresenter not inheriting FontSize property. I have posted a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33658362/workaround-for-fontsize-not-getting-inherited-in-contentpresenter-and-contentcon

Comment: Have a look at blindmeis's answer. You could use TemplateBinding to set ContentPresenter's Content, FontSize etc.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek that really should be the accepted answer. It gracefully avoids all thye gotchas from some of the workarounds suggested here.

Comment: This solution works great, except for the fact that you cannot name the elements inside the user control. So naming the `Button` in the above example would throw an error.

Comment: What is `CalibrationPoint`? The intellisence couldn't find a possible resolution to that class, is it some custom thing? [[ EDIT ]] sorry I didn't check the method `Register` parameters. I think this should be changed to `UserControl1` to compile.

Comment: This is great! How would you do this for multiple elements in `AdditionalContent`? (If possible, I'd rather change the property to allow multiple items than change the usage of the usercontrol)

Answer (score 31):

You have to set the `ControlTemplate`:

```
<UserControl>
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:UserControl1}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:UserControl1}">
                    <Grid Background="LightBlue">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Title" FontSize="30" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you set it via `UserControl.Resources/Style` instead of just putting the  `ControlTemplate` as content of `UserControl.Template`?

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like setting the `Template` property of a `UserControl` isn't supported: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/silverlight/en-US/a41ff344-1760-4e2d-afc2-67307372b584/how-can-set-usercontrols-template-in-xaml

Comment: UserControl.Template works for me. I use TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}".

Comment: Thank you for this.

Comment: Setting the control template disables the use of x:Name within any content you set. Tested in a .Net 4.7 wpf app. Namescope is already set apparently.

Answer (score 10):

You can template the user control to add additional visuals like the `TextBlock`.

```
<UserControl>
<UserControl.Style>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate>              
          <Grid Background="LightBlue"> 
          <Grid.RowDefinitions> 
            <RowDefinition Height="50" /> 
            <RowDefinition Height="*" /> 
          </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
          <TextBlock Text="Title" FontSize="30" Margin="10,0,0,0"/> 
          <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"  />
          </Grid> 
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</UserControl.Style>
<Button>
  Click me!
</Button>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: use `<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">` to make it work in a resource dictionary

Comment: I create a new UserControl that needed to contain content. 
This is the only solution that seems to work properly without causig ton of other problems during implementation or down the road. E.g. @blindmeis solution does not show any visuals in the designer of the control itself. Only in the designer of the control where the new control is used. 
There is still the issue where a control set as content of the new control can't have a name attribute.

Answer (score 9):

Use template with

> < ContentControl />

Instead of using Content Presenter

So place this:

```
<UserControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}" >
                          <Grid Background="LightBlue"> 
                           <Grid.RowDefinitions> 
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" /> 
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" /> 
                          </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
                           <TextBlock Text="Title" FontSize="30" Margin="10,0,0,0"/> 

                        <ContentControl  Grid.Row="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"  />

                        </Grid> 
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Style>
```

to your userControl

Comment: *Use template with ContentControl instead of using ContentPresenter* - Why?

Comment: Better to use ContentPresenter inside templates, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1288353/991267

Answer (score 2):

This is the simple general template for a user control (without using styles or properties to set the content):

```
<UserControl ...>
   <UserControl.Template>
       <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
           <!-- control contents here -->
           <ContentPresenter/><!-- outside contents go here -->
           <!-- control contents here -->
       </ControlTemplate>
   </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

The `<ControlTemplate>` represents the user control's XAML duplicated for each control.

The `<ContentPresenter>` is where the `Content` gets put when consuming the control.