# How to prevent the Content of a UserControl from being overridden?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp

I'm new to Windows 10 app development. I'm trying to embed my custom UserControl in a page in my application. For some reason, the content is being completely replaced by whatever I put inside it in the XAML page. To give a better explanation, here is the code:

**AppView.xaml** (the control)

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Sirloin.AppView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Sirloin"
    xmlns:h="using:Sirloin.Helpers">

    <SplitView x:Name="splitView" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <!--The hamburger-->
                <Button Click="OnHamburgerClicked" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonStyle}">
                    <Button.DataContext>
                        <local:MenuItem Symbol="&#xE700;"/>
                    </Button.DataContext>
                </Button>

                <!--Buttons just below the hamburger-->
                <ListView x:Name="topView" 
                          Grid.Row="1"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewItemTemplate}"/>

                <!--Buttons toward the bottom of the menu-->
                <ListView x:Name="bottomView" 
                          Grid.Row="3"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewItemTemplate}"/>
            </Grid>
        </SplitView.Pane>

        <SplitView.Content>
            <!--Where I'd like the content specified in MainPage to appear-->
            <Frame x:Name="frame" Background="White"/>
        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>
</UserControl>
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="Sirloin.Example.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:s="using:Sirloin"
    xmlns:local="using:Sirloin.Example">

    <s:AppView>
        <Grid Background="White">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Text="Hello, world!"/>
        </Grid>
    </s:AppView>
</Page>
```

When `MainPage` renders in the VS designer, it's as if the contents of my user control have been completely gutted out and replaced with whatever is specified in the main page. To give you an idea, here is a screenshot of the designer:

[image]

As you can see, there is no menu or `SplitView` or whatever I've put in my custom control; the only thing that's present is the `TextBlock` I've specified in the XAML for `MainPage`.

Anyway, why does this happen and what can I do to fix it?

---

**EDIT:** Found the solution I was looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10427404/4077294), but Peter Duniho's answer has been accepted as it provides a better explanation of what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UserControl` is a subclass of `Control` (which is similar to WPF's `ContentControl`). It can have only one child. So you are explicitly overriding the content yourself. By specifying a child element for your `AppView` in the `Page` XAML, you are setting the content of the control. This takes precedence over whatever content was specified in the `UserControl`'s own XAML.

Unfortunately, it's not very clear what it is you expected to happen. Maybe you want to provide a property for additional content, which the `AppView` class can use to add to its own content. Or maybe you should be allowing the client code to provide a `DataTemplate` and some kind of data item object (e.g. model class), which is used in a `ContentPresenter` or similar in the `AppView` XAML.

But whatever you're trying to do, you'll have to do it without using, and overriding the current value of, the implicit `Content` property of the `UserControl` in the `Page` XAML.

Comment: `UserControl` is a subclass of `Control`, not `ContentControl`. It does have a `Content` dp though.

Comment: @JustinXL: yes, thank you. I forgot that the Winrt API splits out the content controls and `Panel` controls differently from WPF. Still, same basic issue applies.

Comment: @Peter Duniho: What I think James means with user control is MainPage. I think he expects to see the Splitview control surrounding MainPage when he opens the designer for MainPage.xaml.