# Error while binding image source in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, image, binding

I have an `ItemsControl` with a Canvas that should show my images. I have an `ObservableCollection` with objects of a class with propoties:

```
Image Image;
double X;
double Y;
```

My XAML contains the following code:

```html
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas AllowDrop="True" Drop="Canvas_Drop_1" MouseDown="canvas_MouseDown_1" Background="{StaticResource LightColor}" Name="canvas" >
            </Canvas>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

where `Images` is my `ObservableCollection`.
Now the problem is that I cannot bind an `Image` from that collection to an `ImageSource` in a `DataTemplate`. If I do it as I wrote, I'm getting an error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 1 : Cannot create default converter to perform 'one-way' conversions between types 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' and 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'. Consider using Converter property of Binding. BindingExpression:Path=Image; DataItem='ImageItemViewModel' (HashCode=7670737); target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='System.Windows.Controls.Image' BindingExpression:Path=Image; DataItem='ImageItemViewModel' (HashCode=7670737); target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')

It works when I put:

```html
<Image Source="{Binding Image.Source}"/>
```

instead of

```html
<Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
```

but then I'm losing all image's properties that it has (like effects etc).

So the question is: How can I put there the whole `Image` object that I have in my collection object instead of binding just its source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Image` property should not be an [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control, but an [ImageSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesource.aspx), or perhaps an `Uri` or `string` instead.

```
public class DataItem
{
    public ImageSource Image { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

or

```
public class DataItem
{
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

---

However, if you really need the property to be a control, you might put it into a ContentControl:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Image}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Yes,  <ContentControl Content="{Binding Image}"/> is what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1287995/1136211) about using ContentPresenter instead of ContentControl.