# Multiple Foreground Colours In ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, microsoft-metro

I have a `Style` for an `Expander`. I want the `Foreground` property of the `Header` to be different from the `Content`.

```
<Style TargetType="Expander">
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="Expander">
        <StackPanel>
          <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>            
          <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="Blue" TextBlock.Foreground="Blue"/>
        </StackPanel>
       </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

<Expander>
  <Expander.Header>
    <TextBlock Text="Header"/>
  </Expander.Header>
  <Expander.Content>
    <TextBlock Text="Content"/>
  </Expander.Content>
</Expander>
```

However, once the `Style` is applied, both the `Header` and the `Content` come back as Red i.e. the `Expander` style `Foreground` colour.

How can I get the `Expander` style to contain multiple `Foreground` colours.

[image: Actual Rendering]

Comment: Have you tried like  <Expander.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Header" Foreground="Blue" />
            </Expander.Header>

Comment: I was hoping to set this in the Expander style, rather than having to set it everywhere I use the Expander.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in template is better to use the `ContentPresenter`, instead of `ContentControl`, which is a common practice. Quote reply `Nir` (Question: [What's the difference between ContentControl and ContentPresenter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287995/whats-the-difference-between-contentcontrol-and-contentpresenter)):

> ContentControl is a base class for controls that contain other elements and have a Content-property (for example, Button).
>   ContentPresenter is used inside control templates to display content.
>   ContentControl, when used directly (it's supposed to be used as a base class), has a control template that uses ContentPresenter to display it's content.
>
> Inside ControlTemplate use ContentPresenter;
>
> Outside of ControlTemplate (including DataTemplate and outside templates) try not to use any of them, if you need to, you must prefer ContentPresenter;
>
> Subclass ContentControl if you are creating a custom "lookless" control that host content and you can't get the same result by changing an existing control's template (that should be extremely rare).

Second, the type of construction:

```
<Expander Header="MyHeader">
    <Expander.Content>
        <TextBlock Text="Content"/>
    </Expander.Content>
</Expander>
```

You automatically overwrites your the `template (style)`, so the color is the same everywhere, because `Red` is set, taken from the `Style setter`.

So, a slightly modified example:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" />
                    </Border>

                    <Border Name="Content" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" TextBlock.Foreground="Blue">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    </Border>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Grid>
    <!-- Work -->
    <Expander Header="MyHeader" Content="MyContent" />

    <!-- Not work -->
    <!--<Expander Header="MyHeader">
        <Expander.Content>
            <TextBlock Text="Content"/>
        </Expander.Content>
    </Expander>-->
</Grid>
```

To study the work style, you can take a predefined style (such as [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753296%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), and change it from there.

`Note:` It is better to design a *universal* template to the content, because if you set the content other than `TextBlock`, color for `TextBlock` will be useless. Perhaps it is better to set the color in style for the `TextBlock`.