# Binding to the TemplatedParent itself

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, controltemplate

Consider a custom control, with a `ControlTemplate` defined via `Style` in a `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
                ....
```

Some where in that template, I have a `ContentControl` which I want to set its content to the `TemplatedParent` itself.

If I bind it to a property on the `TemplatedParent` it works great:

```
Content="{TemplateBinding LayoutMode}"
```

But is there anyway to bind it to the `TemplatedParent` **Itself**? And if not are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using

```
BoundProperty="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyControl}}
```

?

nb: if you're intending to bind a "Content" property to fill the "content" (i.e. visual child) of a control, that wont work...

Comment: That is what I'm trying, And I guess this is why it doesn't work because I get `Logical tree depth exceeded while traversing the tree. This could indicate a cycle in the tree.`

Comment: Even if it worked, your templated parent already is in the tree... you cannot insert it elsewhere. What you're looking for is ContentPresenter, I guess...

Comment: `ContentPresenter` worked! Thanks, So what is the difference between `ContentPresenter` and `ContentControl`?

Comment: In a nutshell, ContentPresenter is made to display elements determined runtime. It may be considered as a **placeholder**.  see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287995/whats-the-difference-between-contentcontrol-and-contentpresenter)

Comment: to know more about it, I sugget you to decompile ContentControl.OnContentChanged and ContentPresenter.OnContentChanged.

They're quite interresting: The first one calls AddLogicalChild, while the second doesnt. (no logical cycle using the ContentPresenter, thus)