# Event Binding doesn't work in ContentPresenter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, windows-phone-8

I'm want to use `Interaction.Triggers` inside a `ContentPresenter`, but for some reasons, the event doesn't get fired.
If I change ContentPresenter against ContentControl, the event binding works as expected.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MapPictureTemplate">
        <Grid Width="80" Height="80" x:Name="Grid">
            <Border
                Background="{Binding Thumbnail, Converter={StaticResource StreamToImageBrushConverter}}"
                CornerRadius="40">

                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main.ImageTappedCommand}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>

            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

and the ContentControl creation in code behind:

```
var content = new ContentPresenter()
{
    Content = this,
    ContentTemplate = Application.Current.Resources["MapPictureTemplate"] as DataTemplate
};
```

Comment: Yes - WP have tap events..

Comment: Have you looked at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287995/whats-the-difference-between-contentcontrol-and-contentpresenter