# How to add a button outside datatemplate in itemscontrol

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate, itemscontrol, itemtemplate

I have created a WPF app.In that I have a Datatemplate as follows

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="item"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
    </StackPanel>
 </DataTemplate>
```

I have an ItemsControl like this

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      Grid.Row="3"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplateWithButton}" />
```

where I need a itemtemplate like this

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplateWithButton">
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="item"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel>
                <Button>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="item"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Is there any possibility of reusing the datatemplate in the new itemscontrol?

Comment: You want to use a DataTemplate inside another DataTemplate?

Comment: As far as I am aware, you can't reuse the template, you'll have to paste your code in.

Comment: @Glen edited the question

Comment: @glen yes if it is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ContentControl too

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="item"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplateWithButton">
    <StackPanel>
        <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" />
        <Button>
            <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" />
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: @Bahman_Aries. That's weird. It should work. Have you tried to bind content property? `Content="{Binding}"`

Comment: @Liero: My mistake, you are right, adding `Content="{Binding}"` in both `ContentControls` is the key for this solution to work.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand by reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1288353/1648849) and what [Liero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/475727/liero) mentioned in the comments is it's possible to reuse a `DataTemplate` by using either `ContentPresenter` or `ContentControl`. However:

1. `ContentPresenter` is more lightweight.
2. `ContentPresenter` is designed to be used inside control templates.
3. `ContnetPresenter` is designed to be used as-is while `ContentControl` is designed to be extended (inherited from).

As a result, here is a solution based on what you asked:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="item"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplateWithButton">
        <StackPanel>
            <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"/>
            <StackPanel>
                <Button Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: What about: `<Button Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" />`? The second StackPanel and second ContentPresenter are redundant

Comment: @Liero: `Content` is the `ContentPresenter` of the `Button`. So your code is basically is the same as mine, and it will work fine. ps, they are not redundant, this structure is what OP asked for.

Comment: The result is the same, but now you have ContentPresenter inside ContentPresenter, since Button contains ContentPresenter in it's template. It's like adding ContentPresenter to ContentControl, because Button is ContentControl acutally.

Comment: @Liero, You are right about the `Button`, it's redundant. I'll modify my answer based on your comment. The second `StackPanel` is also unnecessary. But since OP used one, I'll leave it there.

Comment: I also should correct my previous comment: `Content` in `<Button Content=... />` is actually the `ContentControl` of the `Button`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a UserControl to hold the xaml you want to reuse:

```
<UserControl x:Class="StackOverflow.SharedControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="item">
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Then use this UserControl in both templates.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
    <controls:SharedControl/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplateWithButton">
    <StackPanel>
        <controls:SharedControl/>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="item">
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Why to create usercontrol when you can instantiate the datatemplate inside ContentPresenter?

Comment: I think it is a bit too strong to say "you **need** to create a UserControl".

Comment: Agreed. I have changed it.